# REST API social logins [express.js]

Tags: node.js, express, express-jwt

I am not sure what is smart to do.

Should I check if facebook access token is valid inside in middlware or maybe is better solution to make route which check if facebook access token valid and then return JWT access token to allow user access?

Comment: have you got answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a rest api, do not use logins or sessions. Just send out jwt tokens. Embed all required data in the tokens.

Comment: I need to connect facebook, twitter, google with my api... So I think it is good idea to check for example if facebook access token ok and then to generate JWT to user>?